# Can "the most commonly killed species" be replaced with "the most killed species"?

Tags: sentence-construction, superlatives

I have this doubt about a suggestion from Microsoft Word Processor. My original sentence is as follows:

> This bird is the **most commonly killed** species in Southern Ocean fisheries and its breeding success at many sites is reduced because of predation by invasive cats and rodents.

Microsoft Word suggests I change it to **most killed species**. Is this actually more concise language as Word suggests? I am concerned the idea of the sentence will change.

Comment: If you check the definitions for [most](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/most), you won't find any usage like this. To me, "most commonly killed" or "most often killed" are the best options. In any case, I wouldn't trust any machine translator or grammar checker implicitly. It seems "concise" doesn't cut it here.

Comment: Your suggestion is much clearer than Microsoft's idea so I would leave it.

Comment: In nearly all questions brought here because of grammar checkers, the learner was right and the grammar checker was wrong. The technology is still in its infancy. They're a handy but crude tool

Comment: "The most killed species", while it's clear enough what it means really, gives a slight comical impression of meaning that birds of this species end up somehow deader than any other species!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the suggested change that it is more concise without changing the meaning in a significant way.

That being said, your original sentence sounds fine to me and I would have not have suggested this change if I was proofreading your text.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly precedents for using **most** before a past participle. Here is a typical example:

> It consistently listed among the top 10 NHK programs broadcast on its general channel and among **the 20 most watched shows** on Japanese television in greater Tokyo. - *Broadcasting Politics in Japan, Ellis S Krauss, 2018*

Examples of **killed** being used in this way are much less common, but here is an example:

> Research by MacNulty and others in Yellowstone shows that wolves primarily kill elk calves and cows; they don't start targeting the adults until they are ten to eleven years old, **with most killed being older than thirteen** - *In Wolf Country: the power and politics of reintroduction,Jim Yuskovich, 2015*

That said, I think your sentence is fine as it stands.

Comment: That elk example is a different construction - it means "most of those killed" rather than "those most often killed".

Comment: @A.B. And the mathematical difference between those two being....

Comment: Probably, I was tired at the time and am tired now too.